When a React hook depends on a function that comes itself from a hook, should I memoize it first?
I'm an experienced programmer (10+ years) but new to React (< 2 years). I picked up React in a very "operational" way (i.e. being happy when things work without very deep understanding of its inner workings). Now I'm trying to correct that.
One thing that surprises me is how easily it lets you do the wrong thing. ESLint might warn you, but the fix might be completely misleading. Here's one situation in which I'm trying to figure out what the best practice is.
function MyComponent() {
  const [functionA, functionB] = useMyHooks();

  const shouldOnlyCallOnce = useCallback(() => {
    functionA();
    functionB();
  }
  []);

  useEffect(() => {
    shouldOnlyCallOnce();
  }, []);
  ...
}

Now ESLint will complain that functionA and functionB are not in the dependency array and suggest that I either (a) add them to the dependency array, or (b) remove the dependency array. I think both of these suggestions are wrong, and I'm not sure what the best practice is here.
Here's what I think:
(a) If I want to code defensively, I should not make any assumptions about when functionA and functionB are re-defined. They might be redefined on every rerender. So to go this route, ESLint should also suggest that I memoize them first.
(b) Removing the dependency array would have the opposite effect from what I want, which is to run shouldOnlyCallOnce a single time.
So what's the right pattern here? Do (a) with additional memoization? (But I also heard that excessive memoization can degrade performance).

useCallback does not call the given function, it just caches it.  Could you clarify what behavior you would like to achieve in the example?

Hmm let me add a useEffect to make it clear when shouldOnlyCallOnce is called.

Typically, effect are not meant for functions that "should only be called once". For instance it will be called several times during hot reload in development, so you should make sure that it either doesn't make a difference to call it several times, or that you return a cleanup function. If it's not possible, maybe it shouldn't be in an effect?

You're already memoizing too much. If you want these functions to be called only once after mount, put them directly in the useEffect(). There is no point to either useCallback or shouldOnlyCallOnce.

FYI: https://react.dev/learn/removing-effect-dependencies

According to the ESLint React hooks rules then your option (A) is correct, both functionA and functionB are external dependencies (to the hook) and should be included in the useCallback dependency array such that they are re-enclosed in callback scope when their references change. Option (B) and omitting the dependency array entirely is just about wrong 100% of the time and would be exactly the same as not using useCallback at all. The idea here is to provide stable callback references as much as possible.
function MyComponent() {
  const [functionA, functionB] = useMyHooks();

  const shouldOnlyCallOnce = useCallback(() => {
    functionA();
    functionB();
  }
  [functionA, functionB]);
  ...
}

This creates shouldOnlyCallOnce as a stable memoized callback function to be used/called further down the line, e.g. passing shouldOnlyCallOnce as a stable reference as props to children components.

Removing the dependency array would have the opposite effect from what
I want, which is to run shouldOnlyCallOnce a single time.

If you only want functionA and functionB to be called once, immediately then this sounds more like you want to just call them as intentional side-effects right then and there in MyComponent. If this is the case then you should instead use the useEffect hook.
Examples:

Empty dependency array means invoke the useEffect hook callback exactly once when the component mounts.
function MyComponent() {
  const [functionA, functionB] = useMyHooks();

  useEffect(() => {
    functionA();
    functionB();
  }
  []);
  ...
}


Include functionA and functionB as dependencies when you wish for both of them to be called when either changes references:
function MyComponent() {
  const [functionA, functionB] = useMyHooks();

  useEffect(() => {
    functionA();
    functionB();
  }
  [functionA, functionB]);
  ...
}



Ideally your useMyHooks should also already be using useCallback to memoize and provide stable functionA and functionB references to its consumers, otherwise you force all consumers to do this each time they want, or care, for them to also be stable references.
const useMyHooks = () => {
  // Create memoized callbacks
  const functionA = useCallback(() => { ... }, [/* A dependencies */]);
  const functionB = useCallback(() => { ... }, [/* B dependencies */]);

  // Return memoized array of callbacks
  return useMemo(() => {
    return [functionA, functionB];
  }, [functionA, functionB]);
};


Thanks Drew! A follow-up question: what if functionA and functionB are really expensive and I want to make sure that they don't get called more than once (even if the implementation of useMyHooks is silly and might redefine them on each render)?
Should I wrap them in useCallback first? (My original shouldOnlyCallOnce was trying to be slightly more efficient than that by making a single useCallback wrapper instead of two).

@Joseph Are the actual function calls themselves expensive/heavy, or is creating/declaring the functions expensive/heavy? If the function calls themselves are heavy then memoization is not the tool that solves that... that heavy logic is unavoidable because it happens when the function is called (maybe you can make improvements further up the call-chain/stack). But if creating the callbacks is heavy, this is where making them as stable as possible references is useful. Does this make sense?

@Joseph Also, memoization in terms of React performance typically revolves around providing stable references so as to not trigger additional unnecessary component renders, not as a solution to function calls with heavy logic. Obviously in plain Javascript memoization is a tool that can help cache heavy computations in functions, but this has nothing to do with React hooks.
